# Nuclear Magnetic Resonance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, resonance

Can you recommend a good book on NMR for beginners or something like that. I know QM and classical electrodynamics.

Comment: Well, supposedly I know that. :)

Comment: Something like Pulse and Fourier Transform NMR. But that I can find in pirate bay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abragam - The principles of nuclear magnetism

Levitt- Spin dynamics, Basics of nuclear magnetic resonance

Slichter - Principles of Magnetic Resonance